# How do i update the list view

Tags: android

```
  Cursor smCursor = getContentResolver().query( 
            Uri.parse("content://contact"),
            new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" }, "address like?",
            new String[] { searchContactPhone }, null); 
CustomAdapter ada = new CustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.sm_layout, smCursor, new String[] {
                        "body" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.txt2 });
        lvSm.setAdapter(ada);

btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            ArrayList<Boolean> ca = ada.getItemsThatAreChecked();
            // this ArrayList will hold our Strings from the rows that were clicked.
            ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            int s = ca.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                    if (ca.get(i).booleanValue()) {
                            smCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                            Log.v("sss", smCursor.getString(smCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                            results.add(smCursor.getString(smCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                    }
            }
            if(results != null && !results.isEmpty()){
                String [] mSelectionArgs  = results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
                String mSelectionClause = "_id=?";
                int delCursor = 0;

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://contact");
                for(int delCount = 0;delCount < mSelectionArgs.length;delCount++)
                {
                delCursor = getContentResolver().delete(uri ,mSelectionClause,new String[]{mSelectionArgs[delCount]});
                }
                ada.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mSelectionArgs.length +" number of rows deleted", 5).show();

            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry no deletion occurs", 5).show();


        }
```

I want to know that how can i update my list view, as i am deleting the selected items from my list view and after deletion the selection automatically takes place to next items.I have used the notifyDataSetChanged() but not works. I am using the Custom adapter.

Comment: might be some issue with overriding. Check out similar (identical) questions here on SO

Comment: You have to requery the cursor or if you are using cursor loader then call restart loader.

Comment: Please include the code that creates the adapter `ada` so we can see how you bind data to your ListView.

Comment: @Sam I have added the code of adapter.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. Please post how you populate 'smCursor' as well. I want to see where the data is gathered from to make sure that it is being deleted.

Comment: @Sam, I have added the code of smCursor and custom adapter as well. Kindly help please...

Comment: Have you confirmed that the log "sss" outputs the correct ids?

Comment: @Sam, yes the sss output showing the correct ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            ArrayList<Boolean> ca = ada.getItemsThatAreChecked();
            // this ArrayList will hold our Strings from the rows that were clicked.
            ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            int s = ca.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                    if (ca.get(i).booleanValue()) {
                            smCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                            Log.v("sss", smCursor.getString(smCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                            results.add(smCursor.getString(smCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                    }
            }
            if(results != null && !results.isEmpty()){
                String [] mSelectionArgs  = results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
                String mSelectionClause = "_id=?";
                int delCursor = 0;

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://contact");
                for(int delCount = 0;delCount < mSelectionArgs.length;delCount++)
                {
                delCursor = getContentResolver().delete(uri ,mSelectionClause,new String[]{mSelectionArgs[delCount]});
                }
        ada = new CustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.sm_layout, smCursor, new String[] {
                        "body" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.txt2 });
        lvSm.setAdapter(ada);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mSelectionArgs.length +" number of rows deleted", 5).show();

            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry no deletion occurs", 5).show();


        }
```

Just working fine, as I only recreate the instance of custom adapter and bind it to list view after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

To make it working after deletion you need to change datasource before calling notifyDataSetChanged method, that can be achieved through smCursor.requery(); method, but as its deprecated method, I would suggest to execute query again, so your code block on click of delete button should be like:

```
btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            ArrayList<Boolean> ca = ada.getItemsThatAreChecked();
            // this ArrayList will hold our Strings from the rows that were clicked.
            ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            int s = ca.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
                    if (ca.get(i).booleanValue()) {
                            smCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                            Log.v("sss", smCursor.getString(smCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                            results.add(smCursor.getString(smCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                    }
            }
            if(results != null && !results.isEmpty()){
                String [] mSelectionArgs  = results.toArray(new String[results.size()]);
                String mSelectionClause = "_id=?";
                int delCursor = 0;

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://contact");
                for(int delCount = 0;delCount < mSelectionArgs.length;delCount++)
                {
                delCursor = getContentResolver().delete(uri ,mSelectionClause,new String[]{mSelectionArgs[delCount]});
                }


            smCursor = getContentResolver().query( 
            Uri.parse("content://contact"),
            new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" }, "address like?",
            new String[] { searchContactPhone }, null); 
                ada.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mSelectionArgs.length +" number of rows deleted", 5).show();

            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry no deletion occurs", 5).show();


        }
```